# MicroSD card is not detected by Windows

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, formatting, sd-card

I formatted my MicroSD card to HFS+ and then back to NTFS from within my Phone device (using an app namely Paragon exFAT, NTFS, and HFS+). Now that I insert the card into my PC (Windows 7), the MicroSD card doesn't show up in My Computer folder anymore. I want to initial and format this MicroSD card to NTFS from within my Windows PC.

Windows Disk Management (compmgmt.msc) can detect the pertaining disk with its drive letter nicely, but shows "no media" inserted. So, it is not possible for me to do format operations on it. How can I get my MicroSD card back to the operation again?

**Update:**

Picture below shows all storage devices currently connected to my PC.

Disk 0 : `WDC WD3200BPVT-00HXZT3 ATA Device`

Disk 1 : `SD/MMC Disk Device`

Disk 2 : `Ricoh Memory Stick Disk Device`

[image: LIST DISK]

At the following, `DETAIL DISK` shows the detailed information for Disk 1; that is my Laptop's SD-Card reader slot. Notice that DISKPART shows `No Media` although the MicroSD card is actually inserted into the slot.

[image: DETAIL DISK]

Also, I get error that the disk is not a `GUID Partition Table (GPT)` when I try to change GUID for `Disk 1`; as follows.

[image: UNIQUEID DISK]

Although using CLEAN for a disk with no media seems meaningless but I've given it a try as with error: 
`Virtual Disk Service error: There is no media in the device.`

[image: CLEAN partition information]

Comment: All comments were deleted by a moderator, but it might be important to salvage the fact that when formatting the card on Windows, the poster reported having encountered cyclic redundancy check errors. This raises the possibility of his having a bad card.

Comment: @harrymc I just checked the disk with `HDD Regenerator` and `Eassos PartitionGuru` for bad sectors; the whole disk is with bad sectors. I wounder why the disk is working so nicely in my Android devices but not working in Windows PC due to seemingly bad sector problem. Is that my sdcard is set locked / write-protected by a malicious Android app?

Comment: Yes, that can happen. You should use a read-only test. For example chkdsk without the /f parameter.

Comment: `The type of the file system is RAW. CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.` Okay, how to fix this read-only problem if that is the case? Also, I have erased all the sectors with zero-overwrite but I am stil getting bad-sector report by the said recovery tools.

Comment: You could just give up. If the card was good, the advice below should have fixed it. I'm going to add an answer to that effect.

Comment: I just summerized this question to a new [question](http://superuser.com/questions/1034882/android-can-read-my-microssd-card-but-windows-cannot). You may also follow it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When formatting the card on Windows, the poster has reported encountering cyclic redundancy check errors on the card.

That, together with the fact that he has tried every other advice given in this
thread, seems to point to the fact that the card contains bad sectors,
in a place which only Windows accesses.

You could continue to use this card on the phone, but not on Windows.
I would still hesitate to recommend this, as there might exist other weak sectors.
In any case, even if you decide to use the card, do not trust it.

Comment: As one week passed with no effective answer after many discussions and trying many advices, I choose this as answer for temporary. However, I think that the discussion should be shifted towards solutions on sdcard being locked, write-protected by malicious apps, or compatibility issues. Specially because having the sdcard inserted in my Android phone, I scanned it for bad sector from my PC by `PartitionGuru`but there was no bad sector with the disk.

Comment: Cool deal for sure!!

Answer (score 3):

I believe Windows cannot read HFS+ partitions, so you'll look for 3rd parties utilities to format your MicroSD.

I'd like to suggest using MiniTool Partition Wizard
http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html. It helped me overcome many difficulties that occur with Windows partition utility. Format your deficient MicroSD using the Format and Apply buttons.

Another solution is to write an image of an identical MicroSD card of yours using Win32DiskImager http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/, if Windows still is able to detect the drive with a letter.

Use Win32DiskImager to read the image of the spare MicroSD card to your hard drive, then write the same image to your inaccessible MicroSD using the same tool.

Another solution is to use other OSs that recognise HFS+ partitions, most likely many Linux distributions, and from there format your inaccessible MicroSD to NTFS. This sounds like a long solution for your problem, but consider it if the above solutions are not taking you any further.

Comment: That is [TEAMGROUP MicroSD card 16G (SDHC I)](http://www.teamgroupinc.com/en/product/MEMORYCards/MicroSD%20Card/COLOR%20CARD). To use your 1st recommended tool, I need a recovery image file. Where can I find such image file?

Comment: @DavidDe you could try one of the images made for single-board computers like Raspberry Pi. For example, [this image](https://dl.bananian.org/releases/bananian-latest.zip) has a small FAT32 partition with config files, it's visible on Windows when you read the card.

Comment: Ok I'm downloading it

Comment: Now that I am aware of your microSD card type, did you use this tool to format your SDXC card ? https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/. Please note that you may need an update to read XC cards from here https://www.sdcard.org/consumers/sdxc_capabilities/index.html#cards-for-pcs
Images may not be found online. Which leaves you 
1. to buy identical SD card (which is not cheap, being class 10 SD card) or borrow someone's SD card identical to yours, 
2. to format it (using the link in this comment), and 
then read its image.

Comment: @Sanny Images are not SDHC-specific. I have several SDHC cards which work just fine with raspbian/bananian images, created for 2-4 GB cards.

Comment: @Sanny , `MiniTool Partition Wizard` shows `Bad Disk' for my MicroSD. Additional information provided for my MicroSD by that tool are : Basic MBR (14.94 GB), File System: Bad Disk, Type: Logical, Capacity: 14.94GB, Used 14.94GB. Also there are no function available for a bad disk in MiniTool Partition. What do you think?

Comment: @Sanny , You mistakenly said `SDXC` but that is SDHC. Yes, I've already tried SDFormatter but I don't remember what error I got. I will try it again. Now, I am writing 'bananian.img' recommended by Dmitry.

Comment: I wonder what options you have when you right-click the bad disk but I presume Format is not available. If you can wipe it http://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/wipe-partition.html thus it might become 'format-able' by MiniTool Partition Wizard. However, I'm not certain this may correct or worsen your situation since having a bad disk is not the result from formatting to HFS+ (MiniTool Partition Wizard would recognise any partition type but not as 'bad disk').

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, I just successfully write the `bananian.img` to my MicroSD. Now, what should I expect after this? The good news is that after writing `banaian.img`, the MiniTool Partition know my sdcard with Primary (Filesystem: other) and Logical (filesystem: unallocated) partitions. However, My Computer folder shows only the drive letter but no disk!

Comment: If you revive your SD card, please be aware that they need special formatting software if you want to keep its speed and life-span. Neither MiniTool Partition Wizard or any software does this but at least they may fix your problem. It's better to stick with the formatter from the SDCard.org next time :)

Comment: @Sanny, one problem: SDFormatter and MiniPartition, calculate the size of my MicroSD as 20M only; while that should be 16GB / 14.9GiB .

Comment: It means you only made a small chunk of the SD card readable but I don't know why 20 MB exactly. Are you sure it is 20 MB for the whole drive or for one partition only? However, I guess you really need an original image of your SD card to restore its original capacity. Consider wiping the drive but think very carefully about this. Very good luck.

Comment: @Sanny, The error given by SDFormatter after writing bananian is `Could not format the Memory Card. Either the drive or Memory Card is not supported by this software.` Okay, I will try to find a clone sdcard and to provide a recovery image from it.

Comment: @DavidDe 20MB is the size of config/bootstrap partition, which sounds about right. You will not be using it anyway. Now that the SD card is seen by your PC, you should remove all partitions from it and create a single 16GB partition (I presume that's what you want) and format it into FAT32 or NTFS.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have managed to format the entire device as one partition, without any partition table. This is entirely legit (your phone is using it just fine), but software that expects every disk to have a partition table may "freak out" and refuse to touch the device.

Basically, all you need to do is to convince your computer to recreate the partition table for you. You have several possibilities:

- if you have access to a Linux machine (booting from a LiveCD should do), you can simply erase the first megabyte of your disk with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx count=2048`, and then run `fdisk` or `gparted` to create a fresh partition table.
- if you're limited to Windows, get a software capable of reading/writing full disk images ("disk" meaning device, not windows drive). Make an image of a sane SD card (smaller that the one you want to recover), and write that image to the malfunctioning microSD. Your microSD should become readable, though it will have partitions of a smaller card. You'll have to delete those partition and create new ones, to use the microSD's full size.

I'm a Linux guy so I'm having a hard time recommending a suitable Windows tool. Judging by the description, [Acronis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronis_True_Image) seems suitable.

PS: as you may have guessed, both techniques will nuke all contents of the microSD card, so back up useful data before trying them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not a Linux guy but I have `busybox` installed on my phone. Is `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx count=2048` can be executed by `busybox` for Android? What do you mean of `fdisk`? Is that an Android app?

Comment: If your phone is rooted, try doing `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx count=2048` from busybox console. I'd expect even Windows will be able to see a clean unpartitioned drive after you zero out the partition table. If your phone is not rooted, such command will most probably fail. Also, you'll have to find out the device name first. On PCs, it's usually `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` etc, depending on how many drives you have. On mobile platforms, your sd card may as well be called `/dev/mmcblk0`, `/dev/mmcblk1` etc. `mount` command (again inside busybox) should give you device names.

Comment: There are `/dev/block/mmcblk0` , `/dev/block/mmcblk0pX` where X=1-10; and `/dev/block/mmcblk1` and `/dev/block/mmcblk1p1` . I am not sure which is one that you are referring to. FYI, my MicroSD's path is `/storage/sdcard1` so I guess that I should use either `mmcblk1` or `mmcblk1p1` in your piece of code. Please help me on this.

Comment: Warning: Names of mounted partitions and device names are not nessecary identical. It might very well be /dev/block/mmcblk0 and /storage/sdcard1.

Comment: @Hennes, I am afriad that `mmcblk0` is reffering to the my phone's internal storage. However, I tried `busybox dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/mmcblk1`; after that `AParted` couldn't detect the MicroSD card.

Comment: Does your phone lock down the SD card (that  the the S in the SDcard name part. The ability to lock a SD card to a certain hardware device only) ? If not, can you confirm that this is not the case?

Comment: @DavidDe `mount` command should tell you which device is mounted as `/storage/sdcard1`. Assuming it was `/dev/block/mmcblk1`, and you wrote zeroes on it with `dd`, what is the current status? Is the card being detected by your phone? by your PC? does it still have data or was it effectively blanked?

Comment: @Hennes, I'd be interested to see a reference on how to lock an SD card to a particular device. How do you expect the OP to respond to your question without explaining how to lock the card, and how to check it is locked?

Comment: @Hannes, That is a [TEAMGROUP MicroSD card 16G (SDHC I)](http://www.teamgroupinc.com/en/product/MEMORYCards/MicroSD%20Card/COLOR%20CARD)

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev, I get error like "sdcard is damaged. Try to reformat it" when I try to mount sdcard for the very first time. -> After reformatting, the sdcard is successfully mounted and ready to use. -> the output of `busybox mount` is
`/dev/block/vold/179:65 on /storage/sdcard1 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev, noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0002, dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)`

Comment: No idea how to do that. All I have is hearsay and wikipedia:

`A host device can lock an SD card using a password of up to 16 bytes, typically supplied by the user. A locked card interacts normally with the host device except that it rejects commands to read and write data.`   

I guess that it should not show "no media" though. I would expect an error.

Comment: @DavidDe Well, if blanking `/dev/block/mmcblk1` damages the file system, it's safe to assume it's the same as `/dev/block/vold/179:65`. You should extract that "damaged" SD card and format it using your Windows machine. Run `dd` again if you have reformatted it with your phone.

Comment: @Dmitry Grioryev, Alright. I did `busybox dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/vold/179:65 count=2048` - Now, before removing the MicroSD card from my phone, should I "Unmount SD Card" from Android setting or without?

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the sd-card into your android phone or tablet and format it to **FAT32 format**. Then check if it is recognized by the PC. If it is then format it to **NTFS** using the PC.

Can't Comment(Not enough points)...

Comment: I have already tried this but to no avail. My phone or tablet successfully formats (FAT32) the damaged sd-card but when I remove this MicroSD card from the phone and then to insert it into my PC card-reader slot, Windows doesn't detect MicroSD card inserted. Surperisingly, only if I connect my Phone (with MicroSD card installed) to PC via USB cable with `Mass Storage Device` option, Windows can detect and access this MicroSD card from the phone.

Comment: try the answer provide here - http://ccm.net/forum/affich-55032-my-micro-sd-card-is-not-detected-by-computer

Comment: As phone (with this MicroSD card installed in the phone) connected to PC via USB as Mass Storage Device, I try to reformat the card from PC (as if it is inserted to PC card-reader slot) but I get errors `DiskPart has encountered an error: Access is denied.' or `You do not have suffcient rights to performe this operation.' Yes, Windows command-prompt's been already started as `Administrator`.

Comment: @DavidDe Try below steps.Plug it in as mass storage device.  1. Open Start -> Run... 
2. type diskmgmt.msc and press enter 
3. right click on the partition you want to format (where the letter and size is)
4. select 'Delete Partition...' and confirm 
5. right mose button in the same place and select 'Create partition' 
6. select primary partition 
6. select size, file format, disk letter, label etc should be all right if you leave defaults. 
7. click ok

Comment: `DISKPART` and `Disk Management` are same tools. BTW, there is not partition for my MicroSD card. It is in RAW format. See the comments, I just added below @harrymc above.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing happened to me just now. Used SD Card Formatter from the *actual* SD Card Org. The laptop went to sleep while formatting the card and later never finished when I woke it up.
Tried most of the answers above and nothing worked the Partition MiniTool stayed on the splash screen untill taking the card out of the reader.
What actually solved my problem is my old Nikon digital camera. Plugged the card in and formatted it using the menu option. Now the card has a fat32 and works as a charm. Just find a device that can erase your card. 
Cheers!

Comment: This sounds like another workaround huh?